# An infinite presentation of a group - definition

Tags: group-theory

A *finite presentation* is a presentation where the set of generators and the set of relators are finite ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group))

I'm studying for an exam where one of the "exam topics" is: The example of the infinite presentation.

**But what is an infinite presentation?** From the finite presentation my first thought was a presentation where the set of generators and the set of relators are both infinite. But since I can't find any example on this in my notes, I suspect that the definition only requires that the set of relators is infinite.

Comment: Would $\Bbb Z^{\infty}$ be a suitable group? The set of generators is not finite in this case.

Comment: An infinite presentation is a presentation which isn't finite. That means that either the number of generators or the number of relations is infinite. (But an infinitely presented group is not a group admitting an infinite presentation; rather, it's a group not admitting a finite presentation.)

Comment: An interesting example is the abelian group $C_{p^\infty}$ for a prime $p$, which has the presentation $\langle x_i\ (i \in {\mathbb N}) \mid x_1^p=1, x_{i+1}^p=x_i \forall i>0 \rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example: Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots\}$ be a set. Let $G$ be the (free) group generated by $A$ subject to $a_i^2 = 1$. The presentation is infinite because the set of generators is infinite.